# Javascript Array.join with escaped string characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, escaping, double-quotes

we are facing an issue with the Array.prototype.join method in Javascript.
We have a string Array with HTML string parts.
These parts contain several escaped double primes (\").
Within the title and the text of our HTML element, we have the string

> 4" display

The array we use join on looks like this:

```
var myArray = [
    "<a href=\"", 
    "http://www.example.com/", 
    "\"", 
    " ", 
    "title=\"", 
    "4\" display", 
    "\"", 
    ">", 
    "4\" display", 
    "</a>"
];
myArray.join('');
```

And the output of this code snippet resolves to:

```
'<a href="http://www.example.com/" title="4" display">4" display</a>'
```

As you can see, this is not really the HTML element we hoped for.
We hope to create something like this instead:

```
'<a href="http://www.example.com/" title="4\" display">4\" display</a>'
```

We tried to escape the backslashes once more:

```
"4\\\" display",
```

but this just resolved to

```
'<a href="http://www.example.com/" title="4\\" display">4\\" display</a>'
```

Also, we do not have control over the title and text here (input data from a source we can't control), so we cannot use a different ASCI character for the double primes.

We also tried to change the array entries to template strings instead:

```
var myArray = [
    `<a href="`, 
    `http://www.example.com/`, 
    `"`, 
    ` `, 
    `title=\"`, 
    `4\" display`, 
    `\"`, 
    `>`, 
    `4\" display`, 
    `</a>`
];
myArray.join('');
```

But the result is the same:

```
'<a href="http://www.example.com/" title="4" display">4" display</a>'
```

Is there any way to write this differently, so the join will respect the escape sequence?

Thanks and best regards,
Marius

Comment: I would replace the 4" with 4&quot;

Answer (score 0):

You need to take three backslashes, two for getting a backslash and another for `"`.

```js
const
    parts = [
        "<a href=\"",
        "http://www.example.com/",
        "\"",
        " ",
        "title=\"",
        "4\\\" display", // <- escape here
        "\"",
        ">",
        "4\" display",
        "</a>"
    ];
    
console.log(parts.join(''));
```